# How to Display Array from Rottentomatoes.?

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry I am very new in leaning PHP. I have tried to seach this topic, but did not get the answer, hope some one can help me.

I try to display from API Json from Rottentomatoes, If Rottentomatoes Json Output :

```
 {"total":109,"reviews":[{"critic":"Andrea Chase","date":"2014-07-25","original_score":"2/5","freshness":"rotten","publication":"Killer Movie Reviews","quote":"succeeds only as an advertisement for the tablet mentioned every dozen words or so, and that forms the McGuffin chased with sadly ineffectual diligence by Segal and Diaz.","links":{"review":"hxxp://www.killermoviereviews.com/main.php?nextlink=display&dId=1818&subLinks="}}]
```

How i display "Andrea Chase" value it in php?

Right Now i susses to display "109" from "total" value, here is my code

```
e$url1   = 'hxxp://my-url-api-link';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1));
$total = $data->total;

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of this ansswer I put your `JSON` into a variable:

```
$json = '{"total":109,"reviews":[{"critic":"Andrea Chase","date":"2014-07-25","original_score":"2/5","freshness":"rotten","publication":"Killer Movie Reviews","quote":"succeeds only as an advertisement for the tablet mentioned every dozen words or so, and that forms the McGuffin chased with sadly ineffectual diligence by Segal and Diaz.","links":{"review":"hxxp://www.killermoviereviews.com/main.php?nextlink=display&dId=1818&subLinks="}}]}';
```

Now if you do this:

```
echo "<pre>";
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);
```

You will get the `Standard Object` of `PHP` that holds the `JSON`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [total] => 109
    [reviews] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [critic] => Andrea Chase
                    [date] => 2014-07-25
                    [original_score] => 2/5
                    [freshness] => rotten
                    [publication] => Killer Movie Reviews
                    [quote] => succeeds only as an advertisement for the tablet mentioned every dozen words or so, and that forms the McGuffin chased with sadly ineffectual diligence by Segal and Diaz.
                    [links] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [review] => hxxp://www.killermoviereviews.com/main.php?nextlink=display&dId=1818&subLinks=
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Based on this structure you can get `Andrea Chase` by:

```
echo $data->reviews[0]->critic;
```

How this works is:

data is an object with a property called reviews - so `$data->reviews`

Now reviews is an array and we need its first index - so `$data->reviews[0]`

This first index is again an object with a property called critic. So based on the earlier explanation above: `$data->reviews[0]->critic`

The basic idea to keep in mind is that `Array indexes` are accessed as `$array[0], $array[1]` etc.
`Object properties` are accessed as `$object->property1`, `$object->property2` etc.

Comment: HI Raidenace , it very clear explanation , thanks you, it really works now :)